# Is there a way to run a function using variable name?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I've created a python code that automatically join zoom classes at a specific time using the schedule module. This is an example code below:

```
schedule.every().monday.do(join_zoom)
```

Is there a way that i can run the code like this

```
date = "monday"
schedule.every().[date].do(join_zoom)
```

Thanks

Comment: @Random_Pythoneer59 doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, `getattr` is what you're looking for:

```
date = "monday"
getattr(schedule.every(), date).do(join_zoom)
```

If you want, you can try it out with this self-built snippet:

```
class Schedule:

    @staticmethod
    def every():
        return Day

class FooBar:

    @staticmethod
    def do(stringg):
        print('success')

class Day:
    monday = FooBar
    tuesday = FooBar


schedule = Schedule
getattr(schedule.every(), 'monday').do('ciao')
```

Comment: Please don't repeat answers that are already present on the duplicate I linked.

Comment: I didn't see the duplicate as we posted at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Sure, a simple if-else statement will do:

```
date = "monday"

if date == "monday":
    schedule.every().monday.do(join_zoom)
elif date == "tuesday":
    schedule.every().tuesday.do(join_zoom)
```

etc.